# How to install specific version of windows sdk using chocolatey?

Tags: windows, azure-pipelines, chocolatey

I have C++ project with its target platform version type as 10.0.15063.0 and target platform as Windows 10.

I tried to create a azure pipeline that builds and publishes the artifacts, but I am facing issue to install windows sdk of specific version using choco(i.e 10.0.15063.x).

command tried :

```
choco install windows-sdk-10.0 --version=10.0.15063
```

I am getting error saying the package not found in the sources listed. Is there any way to fix the issue.

Comment: did you check this version is available in https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version `10.0.15063.0` is not in the choco package list. As an alternative, you can download the installation from [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/), and install it via command.

Download bash command:

```
curl -LO "https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/1/B/E1B0E6C0-2FA2-4A1B-B322-714A5586BE63/windowssdk/winsdksetup.exe"
chmod 777 winsdksetup.exe            # add permission for execution
```

Install in powershell silently:

```
Start-Process winsdksetup.exe -ArgumentList "/q" -Wait
```

Verify the version on my local machine:
[image]

However, the version number is strange, it shows 10.1.15063 actually in control panel.
[image]

So I can install it with choco command instead:

```
choco install windows-sdk-10.1 --version=10.1.15063.468 -y
```

Please check the version in regedit and control panel.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like that version is available. You can confirm this by searching for the package and listing all versions using `choco search -a` (shorthand for `--all-versions`):

```
choco search -a windows-sdk-10.0
```

Today, only one version is available: `10.0.26624`. You can try to get the attention of the package maintainer on the [package listing](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/windows-sdk-10.0) via the comments or Contact Maintainers link in the sidebar to update it or you can build your own and host on an internal feed for your use case.

Comment: the -a argument has been removed from the list command. I had to use choco search windows-sdk-10.0 instead and it seemed to work.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer with a command that works with 2.x versions of Chocolatey.